# Not able to bind Flask's Server-Sent Event's data in Angular

Tags: python, angular, flask, events, stream

I am using Flask for backend and Angular for frontend. I am implementing Server-Sent Events (SSE) for some task. Unfortunately, I am not able to receive any data from the SSE.

**Banckend:**

```py
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            yield 'data: some data\n\n'
    
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

**Frontend:**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  var eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/stream')

  eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.data); // Not working
    this.eventData = e.data; // Not working
  }
}
```

The issue with this code is the if I am commenting `time.sleep(1)` line in the backend, then I am able to see the response in the Chrome's dev tools, but not able to bind it in the HTML file. So, if I keep it like that, then I am not able to see either of them.

I am facing one more issue, when I am terminating the backend (by killing the command promt), I am able to see that the failed calls are still being continuously made from the browser to the event stream. I believe, SSEs are always sent from the server/backend, but in this case the client/browser is requesting for the event. Is my understanding wrong?

I have attached an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: can you try this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@chrisbautistaaa/server-sent-events-in-angular-node-908830cc29aa) the angular part alone!

Comment: @NarenMurali, no luck.

Comment: If I am using `eventSource`'s `addEventListener` method like `eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => { ... }`, I am able to bind it as well as see the messages in the Chorme's dev tools. But, I am not able to understand the second part. Even after terminating the backend, why the client is still making frequent calls to the stream, as if it's polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eventSource`'s `addEventListener` method:

```js
eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  this.eventData = e.data;
});

eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => { // This will properly close the stream, when it ends.
  eventSource.close();
});
```